# Field spearator to used if they are not escaped using awk

Tags: unix, awk

i have once question, suppose i am using "=" as fiels seperator, in this case if my string contain for example

```
abc=def\=jkl
```

so if i use = as fields seperator, it will split into 3 as

```
abc def\ jkl
```

but as i have escaped 2nd "=" , my output should be as

```
abc def\=jkl
```

Can anyone please provide me any suggestion , if i can achieve this. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I find it simplest to just convert the offending string to some other string or character that doesn't appear in your input records (I tend to use RS if it's not a regexp* since that cannot appear within a record, or the awk builtin SUBSEP otherwise since if that appears in your input you have other problems) and then process as normal other than converting back within each field when necessary, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
abc=def\=jkl

$ awk -F= '{
   gsub(/\\=/,RS)
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      gsub(RS,"\\=",$i)
      print i":"$i
   }
}' file
1:abc
2:def\=jkl
```

* The issue with using RS if it is an RE (i.e. multiple characters) is that the gsub(RS...) within the loop could match a string that didn't get resolved to a record separator initially, e.g.

```
$ echo "aa" | gawk -v RS='a$' '{gsub(RS,"foo",$1); print "$1=<"$1">"}'
$1=<afoo>
```

When the RS is a single character, e.g. the default newline, that cannot happen so it's safe to use.

Comment: +1  ED, I can always learn something new from you! you are awk Master! but if I really worked on this, I would not do with your solution or mine, I would do some preprocessing. anyway +1 for showing trick that I didn't think of.

Comment: @Kent - yeah, if I have a big awk script and have a convenient control char that i know couldn't appear in my input then I'd do `sed 's/old/new/' | awk 'real work' | sed 's/new/old/'` just to separate this fluff from the real work. Ditto if I want to use an RS that's not a single character and I don't want to be gawk-specific. The cute thing about the approach above using RS though is that you don't need to identify a string that can't appear in your input which I think makes it an attractive solution.

Comment: But still i dont find it coorect , i am geting this as an output abc def and jkl as a seperate , and i didn't get about the limitaton of RS

Comment: Maybe you're using old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris)? The script I posted will work in any other awk. Try `awk --version` and see what it tells you. Also, update your question with a copy/past to show you cat-ing the input file, running the awk command, and exactly the output you're getting.

Comment: For the RS discussion - don't worry about it unless you're setting RS to more than one character which is only possible in GNU awk.

Comment: For awk verion i am getting this error:$ awk --version
awk: Not a recognized flag: -
Usage: awk [-u] [-F Character][-v Variable=Value][-f File|Commands][Variable=Value|File ...]
and i am using on AIX

Comment: again if you want help: update your question with a copy/paste to show you cat-ing the input file, running the awk command, and exactly the output you're getting.

Comment: [ $ awk --version awk: Not a recognized flag: - Usage: awk [-u] [-F Character][-v Variable=Value][-f File|Commands][Variable=Value|File ...] ]

Comment: @chandra - I'm not asking you to keep running `awk --version` and post the result in a comment, I'm asking you to CAT THE INPUT FILE and RUN THE SCRIPT I POSTED and copy/paste the contents of your screen into your original question so we can see what you ran and exactly the output of THAT.

Comment: By the way the result of your `awk --version` tells us that it's not old, broken awk but neither is it a POSIX awk. I would guess you're probably running mawk which is a minimally featured awk optimized for speed of execution. You should use a different awk, preferable GNU awk (gawk).

Answer (score 1):

If it is like the example in your question, it could be done.

awk doesn't support look-around regex. So it would be a bit difficult to get what you want by setting `FS`.

If I were you, I would do some preprocessing, to make the data easier to be handled by awk. Or you could read the line, and using other functions by awk, e.g. `gensub()` to remove those `=` s you don't want to have in result, and `split`... But I guess you want to achieve the goal by playing `field separator`, so I just don't give those solutions.

However it could be done by `FPAT` variable.

```
awk -vFPAT='\\w*(\\\\=)?\\w*' '...' file
```

this will work for your example. I am not sure if it will work for your real data.

let's make an example, to split this string: `"abc=def\=jkl=foo\=bar=baz"`

```
kent$  echo "abc=def\=jkl=foo\=bar=baz"|awk -vFPAT='\\w*(\\\\=)?\\w*' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'
abc
def\=jkl
foo\=bar
baz
```

I think you want that result, don't you?

my awk version:

```
kent$  awk --version|head -1
GNU Awk 4.0.2
```

Comment: Thanks For your input but i have tried this but i am getting the whole string as an output i.e abc=def\=jkl=foo\=bar=baz , but not the seperated one. Why is awk can't limit with the delimiter which is escaped